# Pandas dataframe. Wrong series fly in the line

Tags: python, pandas

[image]
I want to have 81 rows x 1 columns.
How to correct this distortion?

Answer (score 1):

Use `fillna`. Basically, use the values in the second column to fill holes in the first column:

```
df['first_column'].fillna(df['second_column'])
```

For example, if you have DataFrame `df`:

```
     a      b
0  1.0    NaN
1  2.0    NaN
2  NaN  100.0
```

then

```
df['a'] =  df['a'].fillna(df['b'])
df = df.drop(columns=['b'])
```

Output:

```
       a
0    1.0
1    2.0
2  100.0
```

Comment: @IR_ glad that it worked. please consider accepting the answer (by checking the tick mark) thanks